# Convert Grayscale Image to Binary Without Thresholding

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to process the elements in a grayscale image (`cv::Mat`) and assigning it either 1 or 0 depending if it meets a certain criteria. So now, the question arises how to create a binary image from those 1's and 0's that got produced. Well, reason I am asking is because I want to throw that binary image as an argument for `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, like this person did in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpfrq1eRpEs)  *(I am assuming you can pass a binary image for Lucas-Kanade, apologies if it's not, I'm still rather new to OpenCV)*.

Anyways, should I just declare a new `cv::Mat binImg(grayImg.rows, grayImg.cols, CV_8UC1);` and iterate to that matrix to assign my values?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: While this approach *can* work for very dense b&w images, I would not recommend it; optical flow operates under an assumption of brightness constancy which is heavily violated by b&w images. Now if you have *enough* b&w pixels that are unchanging in both frames it could work, but do note you are applying the algorithm in a way which violates its own assumptions.

Comment: But yes that approach is how you would create the `Mat`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thank you again for answering. I did not know that about binary images and optical flow. I was riding on the hope that I can just perform a semi-dense optical flow operation based on that person's video in order to process the set of points that will come from the result of calling `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [compare](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html):

C++: void compare(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, int cmpop)

The key idea is to encoding your criteria in a mat with the same size and use it to compare with the source image. Here is an example.

Let say that your criteria is a parabola curve:

[image]

Such that x is the image row (0-512) and y is the regular gray scale (0-255). Given this criteria it is possible to draw a gray image:

[image]

At than use compare to apply the criteria to the pic:

[image]

I used a parabola in this example, of course you should to adapt the model for your own criteria and needs.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include "opencv2/photo.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    Mat src = imread("Lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    namedWindow("src", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("src", src);

    Mat someGradientMat(src.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(0));

    int limit = src.size().height;

    double a = -255.0*4.0 / (limit*limit);
    double b = 255.0*4.0 / limit;
    double c = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < limit; r++) {

        //value is the parabole y = ax^2 + b + c
        int value = (int)(a*r*r + b*r + c);

        someGradientMat.row(r).setTo(value);
    }
    namedWindow("someGradientMat", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("someGradientMat", someGradientMat);

    Mat dst;
    compare(src, someGradientMat, dst, CMP_LT);

    namedWindow("dst", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("dst", dst);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```